# GameQuery Collision Detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision-detection, gamequery

I am having a problem with GameQuery (jQuery) collision detection

Tthey just never seem to fire?!?
I have checked all the .arrow's exist and the same for the .bot's but it just never seems to call the function

I have the below code in my main callback:

```
$(".bot").each(function(){
 $(this).collision(".arrow").each(function(){
  alert("Test");
 });
});
```

Do you have any idea why this would just simply be doing nothing? The bot walks (has it's x value) moved right over the arrow.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the arrows are nested in a group. So you need to add the group to the collision detection:

```
$(this).collision(".arrow,.group").each(function(){
```

or

```
$(this).collision(".arrow,#arrows").each(function(){
```

Don't worry the groups are not returned by the collision() function. You just need to include them in the filter otherwise their children won't be checked for collision.